# Character encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

For this piece of code:

```
String content = String.Empty;
ListenerStateObject state = (ListenerStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
Socket handler = state.workSocket;

int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

if (bytesRead > 0)
{
   state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

   content = state.sb.ToString();
   ...
```

I'm geting 'Ol?' instead of 'Olá'

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your data is probably not UTF8.

Comment: Better show the exact contents of state.buffer, and bytesRead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the stream is actually utf-8 encoded? Try inspecting the raw bytes in the buffer before encoding (there should be 4) and see what the actual byte values are.

Comment: @RedEagle: Is the byte 63 *before* encoding happens? Then your program works right since the input really is "Ol?", but the stream is mangled before it reaches you code.

Comment: As it turns out the stream was ASCII encodend instead of UTF-8, altough I was totally convinced it already was.

Thanks for the helpfull reply

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it's the wrong encoding.

But if you use this code to receive blocks of bytes (split by a protocol) you will have a serious flaw:  there is no guarantee that the block were independently encoded.

Simple case: the boundary of 2 blocks cuts through a multi-byte encoded char.

Best solution: Attach a TextReader to your Stream.

Answer (score -1):

Are you outputting the result into something that understands 'complex' encoding?

Comment: The result is a .NET string, nothing encoded/complex about it.